# Get value from hidden inputs with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can get value from cName inputs:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="cName" value="test1" />
  <input type="submit" name="get" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="cName" value="test2" />
  <input type="submit" name="get" />
</form>
```

I want when I click get with jquery or javascript to get value from cName.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why would you give the inputs the same name, and no id?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald if you're going to have many form submits that are generated dynamically then I could see the use for this. Though an id of "something_++count" would work well too.

Comment: @jholloman yeah dynamically generated id's would get my vote too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "click," do you mean click the submit button, thus submitting the form? If so, you should use the `submit` event instead, as it will also be triggered when the user presses the Enter key:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    // finds the relevant input based on the submitted form
    // and then gets the value of that input
    var val = $(this).find("input[name='cName']").val();
    // the following line prevents the form submission, which I assume
    // you want to do because getting the value would otherwise be useless
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give the value of the form you've clicked, not the value from the other form:

```
$("[name=get]").click(function () {
    alert($(this).closest("form").find("[name=cName]").val();
    return false;  // prevent the submission
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('input[name="get"]').click(function(){
  alert($(this).closest('form').find('input[name="cName"]').val());
 return false;
});
```

try this link http://jsfiddle.net/RqrH8/1/

Answer (score 1):

The following will return an array of the values you seek.

```
var arrCnameValues = $("input[name=cName]").map(function(i,c){ return c.value; });
```

arrCnameValues will be ["test1","test2"] ... you can then manipulate the results as you would any array of text values.

```
arrCnameValues.join(',');
```

= test1,test2

```
arrCnameValues[0];
```

= test1

Comment: How to get value from this array?

Comment: Also, most of the answers here are very incorrect. The val() method (even on a collection of jQuery objects) will only return the value of the FIRST element in the matched set. So, $("input") matches all form inputs on the page, but $("input").val() will only return the value of the first form input on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the selector that you'll want to use, but you'll need to narrow the scope of the selector for both performance and to get only one of the two or more cName inputs.

```
$("input[name='cName']").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
        alert($($('input[name="cName"]')[0]).val() + ' ' + $($('input[name="cName"]')[1]).val());
    });
});
```